# Convert double to string in php

Tags: php

I've a simple question.

I've this `7310093341976450848` number which I needed to echo.But when I echo it gives me this `7.3100933419765E+18`.

I tried

> echo (string)$data;

to cast it to string and then print it but it's still giving the same result.

The number is initially of type `double`.

Comment: You can change the way the number is output, but you can't guarantee the precision. Doubles only have 64 bits of precision meaning a limited number of significant digits. After converting expect your number of look more like `7310093341976500000`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> I've this 7310093341976450848 number which I needed to echo.
> The number is initially of type double.
> ```

Because of the [floating point representation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) used in PHP, once it's stored as a double, you cannot print out that exact number anymore.

This is one of the (many) ways to print out the value:

```
printf("%.0f", $data);
echo number_format($data, 0, '', '');
```

If you don't want to lose precision, store it as a string, or use one of the arbitrary precision libraries: [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) / [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php).

Comment: Nice link. I probably would have wasted 3 pages describing the IEEE 64-bit floating point standard.

Comment: ok i tried `number_format` and it is printing but the last four digits are different `5729905624998615822` what i want and using `number_format` on this i get `5729905624998616064`

Comment: @Mj1992: have you actually read my answer? which part is not clear?

Comment: i read your answer and i need to represent the number same as it is.You told in your answer that `number_format` is one way to do it so i tried and told you the answer.Is it necessary to use the libraries you mentioned to maintain precision?

Comment: really? "you cannot print out that exact number". yes, or, again, as I mentioned, you can store it as a string (but cannot do math with it)

Comment: actually I am recieving the id's from google servers while implementing a gcm service so it's necessary to maintain precision here.

Comment: you are right look above i tried casting it to string but still gives the same result although when i use `gettype` to view the datatype it shows me `string`

Answer (score 0):

Use [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). Here's how:

```
echo number_format( $data, 0, '', '' );
```

Comment: You should explain to him why he's getting this value.

Comment: it doesn't print out the same value.The last four digits are not same.You can see the comment above