# In PHP how can i manage strings with exponential numbers

Tags: php, string, printf, exponential

i have a problem with some alphanumeric strings containing the exponential char "E", these are stored into the db in a "character varying" column, so are strings, but when i try to visualize them in the web page i get an "INF" string instead of the original.
For example the following "55E77583" (that for me must be only a code number of an order) becomes "INF" in the webpage.
i've tried to search a solution and i found the sprintf and printf commands, but after some tries with differents %char combinations i'm not able to obtain the original form of the string.

```
$code = "55E77583";
echo sprintf('%s', $code);
//Gives me "INF"

$code = "55E77583";
printf('%s', $code);
//Gives me always "INF"
```

I really need to obtain the original form of the string, always, in all the possible alphanumeric combinations. How can i do?

Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I get `INF` if I try to print it with `%f` or `%e` instead of `%s`.

Comment: why do you have to use *print*() anyway.. just echo ?

Comment: i only get the string by the db with a simple query and store it in a variable, i'm sure is a "string", i've also added the (string) at the begin, but if i try to show it with a simple echo or with the sprintf/printf i get "INF", because makes the exponential

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to display the value 55E77583 as string on your webpage. Your provided code above will exactly do that.

So somehow your variable must be converted to double or float before, this is why you receive INF because the number is too large to handle with PHP.

Make sure your variable is actually a string by echoing

```
echo gettype($code);
```

This will very likely produce "double". Maybe a type conversion is happening during your select.

Comment: you are right, the variable at the begin was "double", but with the (string) in front has become a "string", however the problem still remain.. also with a string variable i get INF..
I've found this thread [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377317/convert-double-to-string-in-php[/link] seems that converting the variable in a string is not enough.. i've tried also these suggestions but nothing to do..

Comment: ok, given that it does not work by converting the type of the variable, i solved using a simpliest query for get the code value from the db, before i was using a method that for some reasons has converted the original string value in a float value. Now i can echo the code value as it is, Thank you at all!